# How do I give an invalid message for strings that cannot be converted to an integer, via the input() function in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

I am trying to write a program that issues responses to a user depending on the response he/she gives to the question "What is your height?".

I am having trouble with lines 4-7, where I am trying to ask the user to enter a valid prompt (i.e., prevent receiving a string that cannot be converted to an integer).

My code is here:

```
#ask for user's height, and convert reply into an integer
height = int(input("What is your height?"))

#check if user's input can be converted to an integer
if type(height) != int:
    print("Please enter a valid number")
    height = int(input("What is your height?")

#give user a response, based on user's height
if height > 180: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is above average")
elif height > 155: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is average")
else:
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is below average")
```

Any help/advice is much appreciated!

Comment: In your code at the if, height must be an int, as the first line forced it to be such.  In the case of the first line failing to make it an int, an exception would have been thrown

Comment: I would recommend you to simply use one of string methods `str.isdigit()` it returns True/False, depend on if the string containts only digits[0-9]. – Nf4r just now   edit

Comment: Thanks. In general, what is the purpose of the type() function? Are there any good use cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the exception and repeat until you get a valid number:

```
while True:
    try:
        height = int(input("What is your height? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")

if height > 180: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is above average")
elif height > 155: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is average")
else:
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is below average")
```

Example session:

```
What is your height?: abc
Please enter a valid number
What is your height?: xyz
Please enter a valid number
What is your height?: 180
Your height, 180, is average
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters an invalid number, then your program will crash straight away on **line 1** with a **Value Error**.

What I would recommend is surrounding your **input** with a try/catch statement.

```
height = 0
while True: # Will keep looping until correct input is given
    try:
        height = int(input("What is your height?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")

#give user a response, based on user's height
if height > 180: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is above average")
elif height > 155: 
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is average")
else:
    print("Your height, " + str(height) + ", is below average")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am curious, what is the benefit to assigning 0 to height at the beginning of the program? I have not done this in any of my code and would like to learn the reasoning behind it.